# Tor Browser keeps changing IP, and Torrc settings doesn't work

Tags: tor

So, I'm trying to use Binance with Tor Browser and since it blocks most of Tor ip addresses, I can't access it properly, sometimes in middle of trades it says Error 403 and I have to keep changing my identity over and over until I find a good one again. And when I find a good circuit that actually works, Tor changes my IP within a few seconds. Sometimes keeps it up to a minute. I've read a lot of articles and in all of them, they said add this to your torrc file:

`MaxCircuitDirtiness 10`

Which 10 means 10 seconds. I changed it to 3600 so I can have it for an hour at least but it just doesn't work! It keeps changing my ip every few seconds over and over again which is annoying. These are the settings I have in my torrc file. Could anyone please help me how do I STOP my browser from changing my IP continuously? I'm using Tor Browser 9.0.4 (based on Firefox 68.4.1esr)(64bits)

```
MaxCircuitDirtiness 3600
CircuitBuildTimeout 3600
ExcludeExitNodes {US}
StrictNodes 1
UseBridges 1
```

Comment: The default `MaxCircuitDirtiness` is 10 minutes, not 10 seconds, so I doubt you have actually increased it.  `CircuitsAvailableTimeout` default is 30 minutes.

Comment: I promise you, I read your question, and understand you changed the values.